# How to define ColdFusion functions with the access="remote" attribute using scripting?

Tags: coldfusion

The goal is to allow the definition of all functions of a .cfm or .cfc using scripting rather than CFML tags.

I would like to change this:

```
<cffunction name="foo" access="remote">
    <cfscript>
        ....
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Into something like this:

```
<cfscript>
    function remote foo() {
        ....
    }
</cfscript>
```

Or something else, as long as it can be done within opening and closing cfscript tags.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not possible in CF8, made possible in CF9:

> access returnType function functionName(arg1Type arg1Name="defaultValue1" 
>   arg1Attribute="attributeValue...,arg2Type 
>   arg2Name="defaultValue2" arg2Attribute="attributeValue...,...) 
>   functionAttributeName="attributeValue" ... { 
>   body contents 
>   }

[Defining components and functions in CFScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSE99A664D-44E3-44d1-92A0-5FDF8D82B55C.html)

So your function would look similar to:

```
<cfscript>
    remote function foo() {
        ...
    }
<cfscript>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, good thing I just upgraded to CF9. I should also have read the docs, so double thanks.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to remove entirely the script tags from a file, maybe using a special extension such as .cfcs and .cfms that would hint the parser to parse the file a 100% script file?

Comment: if you start a cfc with: component { } rather than <cfcomponent /> it will be all script based

Answer (score 6):

You could also do:

```
function foo() access="remote" returntype="JSON" {
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate method Sam.

Comment: this one is interesting !!